# Formatting currency in .NET

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I am formatting the currency using Tostring() method i m using following syntax

ToString('##.##') it is working perfectly but in case of round number it remove last 2 zero

like for 100 it does not show 100.00 is shows 100.

how can i format in that way means
input    desired output
100      100.00
100.10   100.10

Answer (score 4):

Try `"##.00"` instead.

That will force two digits after the decimal separator.

You can also use `ToString("C")` to use the culture specific format in Windows directly.

Answer (score 3):

First google result.

```
String.Format("{0:C}", x.ToString());
```

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/format-a-string-as-currency-in-c/

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/globalization/locale/currency-formatting) might help. Might be more than you need, but it takes globalization into account which might be necessary. "C" is also a short-cut currency format string that might get you further along.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
.ToString("C")
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you don't want the currency sign ($ in the US) added that "C" gives, you can also use "F2", which is "fixed number with 2 decimal places". It also has the advantage of giving you a thousands separator when you results go over 1,000.00.